# Nginx does not give css files from next js, Error 403. What could be the problem?

Tags: nginx, next.js

[root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrAuL.png)
[403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EJVE.jpg)

Nginx returns 403 when loading css files from the static folder next js. What could be the problem?

Nginx config

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /root/promo/nextjs-coupon/public;

    location /_next/static/ {
        alias /root/promo/nextjs-coupon/.next/static;
        expires 1d;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, immutable";
    }

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 1d;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, immutable";
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }
    
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}


server {
        server_name admin.example.com www.admin.example.com;

        location / {
           proxy_pass http://example.com:1337;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       }
}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I thought there might be a problem with file paths in nginx, but everything seems to match.
In the browser, all paths are also displayed correctly - /_next/static/css/

Comment: Make sure so nginx have read access to the folder `- /_next/static/css/`.

Comment: I ran the sudo chown -R root:root* command on the project. It didn't help

Comment: And nginx belongs to the root group?

Comment: There are two users there. Probably root has some of the processes on www-data. I gave access to everyone

Comment: You have the wrong value for `alias`. The `location` and the `alias` values should both end with `/` or neither end with `/`.